# Moderator tag-merge interface leads to a generic error page (instead of a specific one) for certain invalid input

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, 500-server-error

There was a tag on a site I moderate that was incorrect/superfluous, and which did not need to be merged into any other tag - it just had to be done away with altogether. So I went to */admin/merge-tags* and figured that maybe I could merge the tag into nothing in order to get rid of it (i.e. as an alternative to going through and deleting the tag on each individual question). Having tried this, I now see that this doesn't work; the bug here is that there should be a specific error message about this at some stage rather than a generic "Oops!" page.

So in the "Old Tag Name" field, I put the tag I want gone, and I leave the "New Tag Name" field blank:

> [image]

When I hit "Preview Merge", I see this:

> [image]

At this stage, I should probably have gotten some sort of error saying "You have to fill in the 'New Tag Name' field, dumbo!", but anyway, I continued ahead with "Perform Merge", whereupon I got a generic error page.

> [image]